# Why does this regular expression not match to the end of a comment line?

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python's regular expression to parse a file for comment lines. A comment looks like:

```
.. The comment is here
Not comment
Nope
.. Yup
.. 
.. This and the above are both comments!
```

However, my regular expression `\.\.\s+.*?&` does not match these lines. I feel as though I am doing something wrong regarding the end of the line and the ampersand.

Comment: Your expression means "dot, dot, some whitespace and any number of dots". Did you mean "any character" or "not a dot"? The `.` is not special inside `[]`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. I will remove the brackets.

Comment: Are you reading the file line by line and applying the regular expression to each line in turn ?

Comment: @Sniffer No, I'm using it as part of a larger parser where I input regular expressions to tokenize the input.

Comment: @Kent I was trying to perform a greedy match? Is that not right? Also, thanks for the tip about the `^`.

Comment: @sdasdadas I was posting to wrong place...I add that in my answer. sorry. with `?`, you were doing **non-greedy** matching, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the `[.]` is not correct, it matches literal period.
- you should add `^` too, otherwise your regex matches `foobar.. blah` too.
- the `.*?$` (I guess you had a typo `&` should be `$`)doesn't make much sense...

this should do:

`^\.\.\s+.*`

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- The end-of-line anchor is a dollar sign, not an ampersand. If you're reading this text line-by-line, you don't really need it. Just make your match greedy: `.*`.
- `[.]` is a character group containing a literal dot. It's not the same as `.`.

The correct regex would look something like this: `\.{2}\s+(.*)`.

I would just do it without regex:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('..'):
        comment = line[2:].strip()
```

Comment: I would use `line.strip().startswith("..")` to at least make it robust to white space.

Answer (score 2):

The character for end-of-line is `$`, not `&`.

Here's a simple regular expression to match such lines:  `r'\.\..*$'`

Comment: I looked at this stupid thing for an hour - I don't know why I confused both of those symbols... Thanks!